# how to combine two ffmpeg commands into one?

Tags: ffmpeg, graphics-card, video-conversion, video-editing, video-encoding

I am currently using this command to cut the first 10 seconds of all videos in a folder so the output is the whole video minus first 10 seconds.

```
FORFILES /M "*.mkv" /c "cmd /c ffmpeg -ss 10 -i ^"@file^" -c copy -map 0 ^"done\\@file^""
```

I am also using this command to remove the watermark from a specified video:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf delogo=x=11:y=9:w=152:h=32 -c:a copy output.mkv
```

My question is how to make these two commands into one? I want to be able to trim + remove watermark in one go.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Add the filter to the batch command. Substitute `-c copy` since video will have to be re-encoded.

`FORFILES /M "*.mkv" /c "cmd /c ffmpeg -ss 10 -i ^"@file^" -map 0 -vf delogo=x=11:y=9:w=152:h=32 -c:a copy -c:s copy ^"done\\@file^""`

Comment: Thank you! -c copy was the issue!  if I want to add a text in place of the removed watermark with the same dimensions specified in the command above, what what the command be for adding a text watermark? Thanks again!